# How do I enable bumper cars on any map?

Tags: team-fortress-2, hosting

How do I enable the bumper cars function on my map? What command would let me use bumper cars on any map? I've heard sometimes that if you try to add bumper cars they won't show, is this actually an issue, and if so, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can `addcond 82` to players to do it using cheats, the bumpercar model and sounds won't be loaded if you do that.

You really need a server plugin to do it correctly.  As of right now, there are 3:

- [Kartify](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=250744) by Dr. McKay
- [Bumper Cars](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=250759) by Chdata
- [Bumpa Cars!](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=250763) by Matt_

Of these 3, the first two were updated just today.  I would consider holding off on all 3 for now until their authors iron out all the bugs (such as team switching and such).

Now, having said that, it's possible to make new maps that use bumper cars and at least one is already underway:

This uses either the `addcond 82` command mentioned above in a `trigger_multiple`, or uses [`trigger_add_tf_player_condition`](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Trigger_add_tf_player_condition) brushes.

Comment: Someone needs to do this for the Mario Kart map...