# How do I turn on some features of TF2 on my server?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I am trying to make a server on TF2 and it will be an Idle Trade server with a few other features. How do I enable Roll The Dice, Color Me, and Go Carts?

Answer (score 2):

'Roll the Dice' and 'Go Carts' are both not found in the actual game and need to be enabled via plugins to your server. The 'Color Me' function ought to be able to be used with console commands, but for more info, check this blog post [here](http://www.monagames.net/team-fortress-2/tf2-special-commands-guide/).

For Roll the Dice, you'll need to install the plugin, which can be found [here](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=666222).
The same thing goes for Go Carts, and some plugins for that can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190094/how-do-i-enable-bumper-cars-on-any-map).

Finally, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oWhkjUKAoc) is a YouTube tutorial on how to mod your TF2 server if that is something you want help with.

I wish you the best of luck in getting these all to work.

Comment: You might want to mention Sourcemod, which is how the plugins are installed in the first place.